# ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase<T> missing in .net portable subset

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, net.tcp, portable-class-library, duplex-channel

I've tried to make a wcf service referecne to a net.tcp duplex from a portable class library (VS2012). The generated code refers to some classes of System.ServiceModel wich are not included in the .net portable subset (for eg: System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase).

Is there a way to get wcf duplex channel work in a portable class library? or is it just not supported by now?

thanks!

Comment: Apparently the class you are looking for is not included in PCL at this stage. If possible, you should separate the non-PCL compliant code into  one or more platform-specific libraries.